# 14.04: Keyboard and Mouse Not Working in Login Screen

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mouse

I'm using ubuntu 14.04. After booting, the login screen freezes and I can't use keyboard and mouse, actually no input hardware at all.

In recovery mode, it works fine.
I tried to `sudo apt-get update` in recovery mode and re-boot, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that USB mouse/keyword worked in the recovery mode every time.  The problem is that I end up with crappy graphics mode in recovery so I basically just force the normal boot to go through recovery by adding "recovery" to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in /etc/default/grub.  My line looks like the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="recovery acpi=force irqpoll usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

along with all the options that I have tried and failed.  I also tried the following (from another askubuntu question), which worked for some time:

```
 sudo powernap-action --disable usb_autosuspend
```

However, I think "recovery" is the only thing you need.  You had to press enter a couple of times to continue booting if you go this route, but at least USB works on boot and you have good screen resolution.

PS. I had this problem with Ubuntu 14.04, and after switching to Mint 17, had the same issue.  I tried various options, some worked for a while and then stopped working, but I eventually ended up with this really frustrating problem reboot after reboot.  I don't believe this is a hardware issue, or I don't believe this is a hardware issue that Ubuntu cannot work around.  My dual-boot Win7 had no such problems whatsoever.  I was pulling my hair out and seriously thought about abandoning Ubuntu based distros.